# Secure Rules in Firestore won't work when run my iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I just tried to secure my firestore database and set the following rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }

  }
}
```

when I try to run my app and add a snapshot listener occurs two things!

1. the code inside the listener clousure executes two times and ..
2. first time I can read the document and the second one I can't

swift code sample (the counter variable is just to know the times of execution )

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("CVDYKKxjLHa69RgWqLxwwnEHHCj2").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        return
    }

    self.counter += 1
    print(self.counter)
}
```

console

[image]

I try to change security rules of firestore db but always got the same result it just works fine if remove the rules and let them "open"

Comment: How does the code ensure that `CVDYKKxjLHa69RgWqLxwwnEHHCj2z` is the UID of the currently signed in user? Can you use `Auth.auth().currentUser` to determine the UID instead, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: yes, the CVD... string is the UID of signed user, that's not the problema, the problem is basically the first iteration in my listener all runs ok, but the second one isn't because the security rule block the listener observation

Comment: "es, the CVD... string is the UID of signed user, that's not the problema" Please edit your code to verify/prove that. If you codify such assumptions, you'll find that at some point the assumption won't hold true.

Comment: Ok, thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I just put a few lines of code trying to focus on the main issue, but you're right I assume it will be clearly to understand, I'll modify it ...